# What does scale heterogeneity mean in the generalized multinomial logit models?

Tags: multinomial-logit, heterogeneity, multinomial-probit

I have learned that one property of multinomial logit models or the data used to build these models is scale heterogeneity. What does Scale Heterogeneity mean in the sphere of multinomial logit models?

Answer (score 0):

Normally all your $\beta$ values are scaled by the constant scale parameter $\lambda$, but when you know that you want to make comparisons across differing groups of individuals the scaling of $\lambda$ for each value becomes a problem.

Take a look at [Train's paper](https://eml.berkeley.edu/%7Etrain/scale.pdf) on the role of scale heterogeneity for an detailed discussion in relation to MNL models.